# Syntax Error Message in IntelliJ Cursive Clojure

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, cursive

I'm learning Clojure. I wrote a first-attempt at calculating a Fibonacci number. Here's my code and the subsequent error message.
I have NO CLUE what to correct. My question is: WHAT is the error message trying to say?

```
(defn fibon
        (fn [n]
                (loop [loops n acc 1N acc2 0N]
                            (if (<= loops 0)
                                    acc                 ;; Return the summed F number.
                                    (recur (dec loops) (+ acc acc2) acc)))))
```

> Syntax error macroexpanding clojure.core/defn at
> (form-init1248982153229513778.clj:1:1). fn - failed: vector? at:
> [:fn-tail :arity-n :bodies :params] spec:
> :clojure.core.specs.alpha/param-list (fn [n] (loop [loops n acc 1N
> acc2 0N] (if (<= loops 0) acc (recur (dec loops) (+ acc acc2) acc)))) failed: vector? at: [:fn-tail :arity-1 :params] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/param-list

In general, could someone please point me to some documentation on Clojure in Cursive so I can decipher these error messages myself, if there is such a beast. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you see is a clojure.spec error.  It is telling you that your code violates the specification of `defn`.

The error message is cryptic but if you unpack the error message you can see that the `param-list` clojure.spec failed because `(fn [n] (loop ...` is not a `vector?`

This is trying to tell you that `defn` expected to see a `vector` after `fibon`, not `(fn [n] (loop ...`  It is not the most intuitive error message.

There is the [clojure spec guide](https://clojure.org/guides/spec) but it is targeted to developers of specifications.

There are other clojure projects that provide more intuitive spec error messages.  I've used [expound](https://github.com/bhb/expound) at the command line and it provides much nicer error messages, however I don't think  you can use expound with cursive, but that might be worth exploring.

When I saw your code, I first looked at what the definiation of the  `defn` macro is by doing a ctrl-mouse-over on the `defn`, or you can look at the online [defn documentation](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/defn).  That information along with the spec error let me understand how to interpret the error message.

As for your code, when using defn you don't use `(fn`.  So your code should look like:

```
(defn fibon [n]
        (loop [loops n acc 1N acc2 0N]
                        (if (<= loops 0)
                                acc                 ;; Return the summed F number.
                                (recur (dec loops) (+ acc acc2) acc))))
```

Comment: This is great. Three new facts to file: ctrl+click to see syntax definitions, look for the question mark in the error message, and for what follows clojure.core. When you said "It should be a vector," I knew exactly what I had done wrong. Thank you for taking the time to help me. Now I have to pass it forward.

Comment: The ? is part of the clojure spec syntax and from the spec documentation, "? - 0 or 1 of a predicate/pattern"

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is good.  One suggestion to a question you didn't ask:  you may wish to adjust your IDEA settings so it only indents 2 spaces each line, instead of 8 spaces (1 tab char?).

If necessary, uncheck the box **"Use tab character"**.  Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Then it will look like this:

```
(defn fibon
  [n]
  (loop [loops n
         acc   1N
         acc2  0N]
    (if (<= loops 0)
      acc   ;; Return the summed F number.
      (recur (dec loops) (+ acc acc2) acc))))
```

For the `loop` statement, I like to keep each loop variable and its initial value on a separate line.  In this way it looks similar to the Clojure `let` expression.

Enjoy!

Comment: This is great too! Thank you. And I like your formatting idea. Clojure is so DENSE it's hard to read. Expanding the params like that makes it a little bit easier.